# Configure apache vhost to not treat "?" as a query token

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have snapshotted all the pages on my ajax application, and as per google specification [ http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174992 ]i've stored those files in a pattern described as "www.example.com/ajax.html?_escaped_fragment_=mystate" .
In the same directory there is a file named, adapted to this example, ajax.html , which is a static html page. No server side is involved at all.

When navigating to www.example.com/ajax.html?_escaped_fragment_=mystate , which contains html content which is different from that found in ajax.html , ajax.html gets displayed in the browser, using curl, wget and google's "fetch as googlebot" tool.

From my understanding the problem is that ? gets treated by the http server [apache 2] the same way as # gets treated by the browser, ie it's considered as a query param char.

So, how do i instruct this VHOST to behave correctly, and send out the www.example.com/ajax.html?_escaped_fragment_=mystate file instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could save all your fragments in /fragments/(mystate) and use the apache module mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ajax.html$ /fragments/%1
```

This reads as:
If theres a query string "_escaped_fragment_", take the value, put it in variable %1 and go on. Then, if the url also is 'ajax.html' Rewrite ajax.html to /fragments/%1.